# Setup product with zero price in whmcs for specific client group

Tags: php, whmcs

I have tried to setup free product for user group in whmcs but no luck.

I know that promotion code(With 100% discount) can be used for this. But i need that user associates with specific client group can purchase product for free.

I have googleing for this but not found any solution.

Please help how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a product to be 'free' for anyone - set the price to 0 or select 'free' as the billing cycle on the product.

If you want the product to only be orderable for people in a specific client group, this can be done several ways
* make the product hidden and only give out the link to it to specific users
* put some php code / smarty-if-statements in the template(s)
etc